# Why are my objects invisible and in the wrong places?

Tags: objects, 3d-view

[image]

[image]

When I add an object, it is invisible. When I change to evee, it turns black, and when I move around the view, it takes away from the black and makes it grey. Then when I turn to cycles it turns grey like in solid view. I've already tried rolling back my drivers, and it doesn't effect anything. I am using Blender 2.81. Everything was normal for a while, then all of the sudden I added an object and it was invisible.

When I restarted my computer, it did the same thing but only when I was close. The origin and outline are still there. My clip start was set very low, but even when I change it it didn't change anything.

One time when this was happening, I deleted everything, then added a new cube. It was displayed as one of the old cubes, but the outline was not in the right place.

When I add more objects, some of them disappear and others display the wrong shape. This only happens in object mode, and going into edit mode fixes it.

This only happens every so often, and seems to just magically be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For the out-of-place issue. Your Origin is not centered on the Object. Select the cube when in Object Mode and use this tool to put realign the origin [image]